# mysql user host field in slow query log

Tags: mysql, users, performance, slow-log

Mysql shows the following value in the slow query log

```
# User@Host: user[user] @  [127.0.0.1]
```

I'm assuming one if the "user" entries is a proxied login. An admittedly very quick glance of the code has not come up with how the user_host value is set.

Is this the case, and if so which one?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to know

Login to MySQL and run this

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER(); SELECT SLEEP(15);
```

What will this tell you ?

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

Look for the `SELECT SLEEP(15);` query in the slow log. From there, you should be able to tell whether [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_user) or [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) was used to set `# User@Host:`.